# Translating Matlab's bsxfun to Eigen

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, eigen3

Say we have a matrix A of dimension MxN and a vector a of dimension Mx1. In Matlab, to multiply 'a' with all columns of 'A', we can do

```
bsxfun(@times, a, A)
```

Is there an equivalent approach in Eigen, without having to loop over the columns of the matrix?

I'm trying to do

```
M = bsxfun(@times, a, A) + bsxfun(@times, a2, A2)
```

and hoping that Eigen's lazy evaluation will make it more efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
M = A.array().colwise()*a.array();
```

The `.array()` is needed to redefine the semantic of operator* to coefficient-wise products (not needed if A and a are `Array<>` objects).

In this special case, it is probably better to write it as a scaling operation:

```
M = a.asDiagonal() * A;
```

In both cases you won't get any temporary thanks to lazy evaluation.

Comment: What about C = bsxfun(@rdivide, pts, pts(3,:)); ? My related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741074/from-matlab-to-c-eigen-matrix-operations-vector-normalization?noredirect=1#comment72601063_42741074

Comment: This question has been answered by Peter.