# From Matlab to C++ Eigen matrix operations - vector normalization

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen, matrix-multiplication

Converting some Matlab code to C++.

Questions (how to in C++):

1. Concatenate two vectors in a matrix. (already found the solution)
2. Normalize each array ("pts" col) dividing it by its 3rd value

Matlab code for 1 and 2:

```
% 1. A 3x1 vector. d0, d1 double.
B = [d0*A (d0+d1)*A]; % B is 3x2

% 2. Normalize a set of 3D points
% Divide each col by its 3rd value
% pts 3xN. C 3xN.
% If N = 1 you can do: C = pts./pts(3); if not:
C = bsxfun(@rdivide, pts, pts(3,:));
```

C++ code for 1 and 2:

```
// 1. Found the solution for that one!
B << d0*A, (d0 + d1)*A;

// 2. 
for (int i=0, i<N; i++)
{
    // Something like this, but Eigen may have a better solution that I don't know.
    C.block<3,1>(0,i) = C.block<3,1>(0,i)/C(0,i);
}
```

Edit:
I hope the question is more clear now².

Comment: This is what Eigen is made for.  What problem are you having?

Comment: @Peter, The problem is to fill B in one line like I did in matlab. I think the solution may be B << d0* (*A), (d0 + d1)*(*A); but I did not test it yet.

Comment: Matlab is a high-level language and C++ is lower-level.  Your expectation that one line in Matlab will correspond to one line in C++ is not reasonable.  You get different pros and cons in each.

Comment: @Brick yeah I know. But Eigen have a lot of methods to deal with matrix. I know how to solve that using a loop, but I bet Eigen may have an optimized method to do that.

Comment: @Pedro77 I recommend putting your last comment to me into the question. I would not have understood your question that way. (I'm not a downvote, but I can see why someone might downvote as it's currently written. It's not clear what you're asking at all.)

Comment: agree, please make question clearer.  Code that can be executed will help.

Comment: Why are you using pointers?

Comment: @Bernhard sorry, no reason besides new to C++. Going to update that.

Comment: FWIW Armadillo does what Eigen does but _also_ has the explicit goal to be similar to Matlab.  I use and like both, but use Armadillo more frequently than Eigen.

Answer (score 2):

For #2:

```
C = C.array().rowwise() / C.row(2).array();
```

Only arrays have multiplication and division operators defined for row and column partial reductions.  The array converts back to a matrix when you assign it back into `C`